# What more info does this question require? [I am not new here]

Tags: discussion

I posted a question here - [Can not authenticate device to use with Windows Your Phone app](https://superuser.com/questions/1606712/can-not-use-windows-your-phone-app).

It was closed just by saying that it needed more info. What more can I add to this? I think I have made everything crystal clear or no?

I am just curious and if someone can explain, I will keep that thing in mind for next question.

Comment: You didn’t even tell us if your phone is iOS or Android.  You didn’t tell us what version of the application you are running.  You didn’t tell us which version of Windows you are running.  You have not indicated if you attempted to delete the application off the phone.  That is what we need by it needing more information.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem here is this issue does not seem to be reproducible by others unless more details are provided.

#### What details? In your case honestly I have no idea what you could add that would allow someone here to help you.

> “What more can I add to this? I think I have made everything crystal clear or no?”

You have. But the thing is I doubt anyone here can help you because this seems to be an issue specific to you, your devices and your account.

This seems to be an account issue and the only practical solution anyone can provide is to encourage you to contact Microsoft support and see what they can do to assist you.